# Why is there a need to add a '0' to indexes in order to access array values?

Tags: c++, char, indices, character-set

I am confused with this line:

```
sum += a[s[i] - '0'];
```

To give some context, this is the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[5];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        sum += a[s[i] - '0'];
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s[i]-'0'` converts a character to the corresponding number.

Comment: the '0' is a char value 48, the input is offset by that value, and the acual array starts with subscript 0.

Comment: fwiw, this is quite dangerous code. If user types wrong input (which can be done easily) the code has undefined behavior and anything can happen

Comment: @TedLyngmo, though I understand the close vote (the question clearly points to it), there are some other issues in the code, which makes this question not 100% trivial.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface -- regardless of the character encoding, `ch - '0'` converts a digit to its numeric value. That's true even when `'0'` is not 48. There are systems in existence that don't use ASCII.

Answer (score 6):

`- '0'` (or less portable `- 48`, for [ASCII](https://w0.pngwave.com/png/343/431/ascii-character-encoding-value-table-table-png-clip-art.png) only) is used to manually convert numerical characters to integers through their decimal codes, C++ (and C) guarantees consecutive digits in all encodings.

In [EBCDIC](https://www.allbusiness.com/asset/image/glossaries/4966602.gif), for example, the codes range from `240` for `'0'` to `249` for `'9'`, this will work fine with `- '0'`, but will fail with `- 48`). **For this reason alone it's best to always use the `- '0'` notation** like you do.

For an ASCII example, if `'1'`'s ASCII code is `49` and `'0'`'s ASCII code is `48`, `49 - 48 = 1`, or in the recommended format `'1' - '0' = 1`.

So, as you probably figured out by now,  you can convert all the 10 digits from characters using this simple arithmetic, just subtracting `'0'` and in the other direction you can convert all digits to it's character encoding by adding `'0'`.

Beyond that there are some other issues in the code:

- The array does not start being populated at index `0`, but at index `1`, so if your string input is, for instance, `"10"` the `sum` will be `a[1]` + `a[0]`, but `a[0]` has no assigned value, so the [behaviour is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), you need to wach out for these cases.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

would be more appropriate, indexes from `0` to `4`, since the array has 5 indexes, if you want input numbers from 1 to 5, you can subract `1` from the to the index later on.

- As pointed out in the comment section, a bad input, with alpabetic characters, for instance, will also invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

From the C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)

> 3. ... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>      each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>      one greater than the value of the previous.

So if you have a character for example '4' then to get value 4 you can write '4' - '0'.

If you will write like for example

```
sum += a[s[i]];
```

where i is the character '0' then in fact you will have either

```
sum += a[s[48]];
```

if the ASCII coding is used or

```
sum += a[s[240]];
```

if the EBCDIC coding is used.

The reversed operation of getting a character from a digit you can write for example

```
int digit = 4;
char c = digit + '0';
```

Pay attention to that indices of arrays in C++ start from 0.

Thus this loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i ++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

should be written like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

Also to avoid such an error you could use the range based for loop like

```
for ( auto &item : a ) std::cin >> item;
```