# Why doesn't write() print the numbers?

Tags: c

I have:

```
#include <unistd.h>

//can't use atoi
void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb == -2147483648)
    {
        write(1, "-2147483648", 11);
    }
    if (nb > -2147483648 && nb < 0)
    {
        write(1, "-", 1);
        ft_putnbr(nb * -1);
    }
    if (nb >= 0 && nb < 10)
    {
        write(1, &nb, 1);
        return;
    }
    if (nb >= 10 && nb <= 2147483647)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ft_putnbr(-2147483648);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(-200);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(-1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(0);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(1);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(9);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(10);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(11);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    ft_putnbr(2147483647);
}
```

I get only the first condition but not anything else besides the "-" if I replace it with printf I do get them. But even if I add a new function like:

```
void print(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

and put:

```
print((char) nb);
```

I don't get anything still.
Just by doing:

```
print(nb + 48);
```

Do I get the desired output.
WHAT is going on?

Comment: You really should be using `else if` rather than `if` for all of the checks after the first.

Comment: In any case, you need to understand the difference between `'0'` and `0`.  They are not the same.  Try doing `'0' == 0` and see what you get.  You want to write `'0'` to your file, not `0`, and similarly for the other digits.  `'0'` is a character code.  `0` is an integer whose value corresponds to the null character.

Comment: This line `write(1, &nb, 1);` is writing a single byte on stdout but the byte is not encoded as a decimal digit. You need an array of chars ('0','1',...'9') that you index with `nb` and then `write(1, digitArray+nb, 1);` instead of what you're doing. If you pipe your existing command's output through `od`, then you'll better see what is being printed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a need to add a '0' to indexes in order to access array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994353/why-is-there-a-need-to-add-a-0-to-indexes-in-order-to-access-array-values)

Comment: Problems with `0` vs. `'0'` aside, though, recursion is the coolest way to write `itoa`, which is essentially whats going on here.

Comment: look at [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/1200px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png) (ASCII table). you will find that (char)0 through (char)9 are actually used for formatting like backspace and tab etc or for special meanings like NULL. So, you will not see them as numbers. When you add 48, it's like saying ``0+'0'``` or 48 in the table, which is 0. To sum up, This table maps how chars look like, to how they are stored in memory

Comment: You can think of `write` as being sort of like `printf("%c")`.  And if you compare the behavior of `printf("%c%c%c%c", 0, 1, 2, 3)` with `printf("%c%c%c%c", '0', '1', '2', '3')`, you should see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a character `'0'` to `'9'`, code needs to add `'0'` to the *value* `nb`.  Attempting to print the first byte of `nb` might access its least or most significant byte - depending on [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  IAC, it is not accessing a digit character: `'0'` to `'9'`, but, at best, a value of `0` to `9`.  See [Jeff Holt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

```
if (nb >= 0 && nb < 10) {
    // write(1, &nb, 1);
    char ch = nb + '0';  // Convert value to digit character.
    write(1, &ch, 1);
    return;
}
```

---

For fun, a C99 or later alternative simplification:

```
// Only pass value <= 0
static void ft_putnbr_helper(int nb) {
  if (nb <= -10) {
    ft_putnbr_helper(nb/10);
  }
  putchar('0' - nb%10);  // Go from value to digit character.
}

void ft_putnbr(int nb) {
  if (nb < 0) {
    putchar('-');
    ft_putnbr_helper(nb);
  } else {
    ft_putnbr_helper(-nb);
  }
}
```

Why use the negative side of `int`?
To avoid UB of `-INT_MIN`.